# Lightning Datatable rowspan

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible in lightning-datable component to implement like td rowspan in html?

Like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard lightning datatable tag no , with the help of slds classes and custom css modification it can be done

Comment: gotcha. I guess i have to build this custom way. Thanks Arihant!